# "overload resolution ambiguity" when function parameter is marked "NonNull"

Tags: java, kotlin, annotations

Here are my Kotlin (Version 1.3.61) + Java(1.8.0_201) code that failed to compile:

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Test.Kt:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Point().setX(1)
}
```

Point.java:

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

public class Point {
    public void setX(int x) {
    }

    public void setX(@Nonnull Integer x) {
    }
}
```

Failed to compile due to the following error:

```
Error:(2, 13) Kotlin: Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public open fun setX(@Nonnull x: Int): Unit defined in Point
public open fun setX(x: Int): Unit defined in Point
```

If I removed the `@NonNull` annotation in the second `setX` function, then this demo could compile. I thought Java annotation was only extra metadata and would not affect the code itself, so I had no idea why the ambiguity arose here.

Also, I run `javap -s Point.class` and found out that they had same output:

```
public void setX(java.lang.Integer);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Integer;)V
```

Can someone help to explain what is going on here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe take a step back and explain why in the first place you even have those two methods. I wouldn't see how having both of these would make a difference for the caller

Comment: A similar code was generated from Avro in my project. Though they are not supposed to be called directly, they are public. Therefore I had this question. @LinosaysReinstateMonica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From kotlin in action

> sometimes Java code contains information about nullability, expressed
>   using annotations. When this information is present in the code,
>   Kotlin uses it. Thus @Nullable String in Java is seen as String? by
>   Kotlin, and @NotNull String is just String. The interesting
>   question is what happens when the annotations aren’t present. In that case, the
>   Java type becomes a platform type in Kotlin.
>
> When you use Java declarations from Kotlin, Java primitive types
>   become non-null types (not platform types), because they can’t hold
>   null values.

in your case first method has a java primitve type as parameter and ***because primitives can't be null*** kotlin translates it to

```
setX(x: Int)
```

and since second method contains @Nonnull annotation, kotlin uses this information and hence it translates the method to

```
setX(x: Int)
```

so as you can see for kotlin they are two different methods with exact same signature, hence the ambiguity.